# OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

So, I'm trying to make a 3D grapher for a class. Right now I'm working on understanding OpenGL and I'm failing horribly. I want to move the camera, but I can't at all, whatsoever. Why doesn't this work?

```
public class G3DRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, OnTouchListener {
    float[] camera = {0, 0, 0.5f}, focus = {0, 0, 0}, orientation = {0, 1, 0};

    Square square;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

        float v = 1.0f;
        int c = 0xFFFFFF;
        square = new Square(
            new float[] {
                -v, v, 0,
                -v, -v, 0,
                v, v, 0,
                v, -v, 0,
            },
            new short[] {0, 1, 2, 3},
            new int[] {
                c, 0, 0, c,
                0, c, 0, c,
                0, 0, c, c,
                c, c, c, 0,
            }
        );
    }

    private void look(GL10 gl) {
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl,
            camera[0], camera[1], camera[2],
            focus[0], focus[1], focus[2],
            orientation[0], orientation[1], orientation[2]
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        int dim = Math.min(width, height);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, dim, dim);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        look(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        square.draw(gl);
        look(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the z near/far values have to be >0. No one told me this. So for anyone else wondering why things are horribly broken, make sure that's not why.